# Store highest value from Cell X11 (Live Streamed Data) into Cell AL11

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Cell X11 in which the numbers can range from -5000 to +8000, these numbers change dynamically in the cell from live data streaming in R11 and some calculations is done in S11(User Fed value) for eg. 250 or 300,T11(User Fed value) for eg. 1 or 2, U11(=IF(COUNT(S11:T12)=4,(S11-R11)*T11,""), V11 (=IF(COUNT(U11:U12)=2,U11*25,"")
W11(=IF(COUNT(S11:T12)=4,SUM(U11:U12),""))
X11 (=IF(COUNT(W11)=1,W11*25,"")

What I want is a function which can capture the highest value from that cell (X11) and store it in cell AL11, while X11 being dynamic in changing values based on calculations from previous cells, it keeps increasing or decreasing due to data streaming in R11, the cell AL11 should only manage to keep highest values shown in X11

FYI X11 has formula: =IF(COUNT(W11)=1,W11*25,"")

How can I retain the highest number in these cells (AL11). Can there possibly be a function for this in VBA?

I have no idea where to start, excel MAX formula does not seems to work as per my expectation

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the cell you are monitoring is being changed via formula (*i.e. a calculation*) you can use `Worksheet_Calculate` event to monitor the value as it changes and update cell `AL11` accordingly

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
 
    Dim X as Range: Set X = Range("X11")
    Dim Y as Range: Set Y = Range("AL11")

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If X.Value > Y.Value Then Y.Value = X.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

---

### Edit

This is tested and working for me. Make sure your worksheet is set to auto-calculate and that you pasted the code within the sheet in VBA Editor where your cells of interest are.

Adding a sample of the macro for proof of concept. Cell `C4` is simply taking the sum of the two cells above. Cell `E3` is set to automatically update to the `MAX` output as the sum cell updates over time. Notice when the new value is lower, `E3` does not change. `E3` only updates when the new sum **exceeds** the current value stored in `E3` i.e. your running max value over time.

[image]

Comment: (AL11) does not hold the highest value, it shows me even lower value of X11 when values change to lower in X11

Comment: answering your above question, when the worksheet the opened all cells are blank, the user input is required in Cell S11 and T11 only then X11 is able to calculate the difference in values

Comment: If you see the above image posted just now, once the value changes in X11 to 311.25 the same changed in AL11, however when the value was decreased in X11 to 61.25, AL11 should have retained the value of 311.25 as it was being the highest and not show the lower value in X11

Comment: One sec - let me get my windows computer and test. Just wrote that up on a Mac and didn't actually test

Comment: Did you paste the code on the worksheet of interest in VBA Editor? This works for me. Your excel sheet is set to auto-calculate also right?

Comment: This is ranging from AL11 to AL32 Cells

Comment: Yes i did paste in the worksheet code, whats auto calculate and where to activate it from, workbook calculation is set to Automatic in Options

Comment: If you check the recent image, values have gone into minus in X11 and the same value show up on AL11, whereas it should have retained the value 311.25 being the highest shown in X11

Comment: `AL11 to AL32`? That is very different then your original question. I just updated my solution showing how this works based on my understanding of your question. You initially said you just want to compare the output of one cell so I have no idea what you mean by "*ranging from AL11 to AL32"*. Going to bow out since I am having a hard time understanding what it is that you actually need. Good luck!

Comment: If i have to replicate this to other cells down below for eg X11 to X32 and AL11 to AL32, how will the code be changed, this is doing exactly how i want

Comment: That is a different question and deserves a different post. Have you read the '[ask]' page yet? We are here to provide specific answer to specific questions which means it is your responsibility to ask the right question. You should spend some time making sure you have explained the **full extent** of your problem and also make sure you don't show so many details that are not relevant. In your post, all of the formulas are just extra info that are not needed. Notice my photo showed the minimal amount of data to demonstrate while your screenshot is packed with info (all of which is useless)

Comment: In short, take the info you have now and post a new question. Hopefully one with less distractions and a clear problem statement